# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called and number of row and number of sction and cell height return proper

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i try many thing but it displaying cells

i have add delegate and datasource
tableview.dataSouce =self;
tableview.Delegate =  self;
func cell for row height 
return 44;

i dont know why table view is not displaying

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    int count = (int)_dict_contact.count;
    return count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSArray *arr_email =[_dict_contact objectForKey:@"u_email"];
            int count = (int)arr_email.count;
            return count;
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            NSArray *arr_phone =[_dict_contact objectForKey:@"u_phone"];
            return arr_phone.count;
        }
            break;
     }
    return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MultipleContCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[MultipleContCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
        {
             NSArray *arr_email =[_dict_contact objectForKey:@"u_email"];
            cell.detail_lbl.text =[arr_email objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
              return cell;
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            NSArray *arr_phone =[_dict_contact objectForKey:@"u_phone"];
            cell.detail_lbl.text =[arr_phone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
              return cell;
        }
            break;
    }
       return cell;

}
```

but after trying too much then also my cellForRowAtIndexPath not called

Comment: is your frame okay.

Comment: also have you used tableView.reloadData()

Comment: `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods are called?

Comment: add some logs dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier` for MultipleContCell inside `viewdidload`. For example:

`[_yourTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MultipleContCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MultipleContCell"];`

Answer (score 1):

Check :

1) The `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is not returning 0.

2)`UITableview` frame is correct because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would not be called is when the size or positioning of the table does not require any rows to be displayed.

Comment: Also check if tableview is added to the view hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

1. numberOfSectionsInTableView returns value > 0
2. numberOfRowsInSection returns value > 0
3. UITableView frame > 0

Comment: Thanks for "UITableView frame > 0"

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your ViewController as UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. Something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Comment: You may do so. You may also implement both protocols in own objects and hold the strong reference (e.g. in the viewcontroller). It's more object oriented and it avoids view controllers to grow too much.